# ¿Cómo determinar cambios en el código fuente de una web?

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy trabajando en proyecto sobre una web donde esta web cada cierto tiempo agrega código `html`, es decir para que se me entienda:
cualquier día esta web presenta un código fuente y dentro de una semana se le agregan ciertas líneas,,estas líneas que se agregan corresponden a un botón.

quisiera hacer un código que me permita comparar ambos códigos fuentes y que en caso de haber algun cambio ejecutar algo que ya tengo implementado y en caso de no detectar nada se mantenga comparando infinitamente hasta que aparezcan esas líneas que corresponden la boton..

he implemnetado este código pero mientras no haya botón me falla porque dice que no puede localizar el elemento
cuando hay botón si me trabaja pero quisiera echarlo a andar en ambas circuntancias

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('www.fhfhfhfh.com') # web

boton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="../form_C.."]') # identificando elemento

sourge_page = boton.get_attribute('outerHTML') #obtener codigo sourge boton

empieza =  'a href=.... # codigo obtenido de outerHTML

 if sourge_page  == empieza:# comparar
     boton.click()
 else:
```

Entonces me faltaría por definir que poner después de `else` y resolver el problema de cuando no aparece el botón y `python` me da error, por ende no puedo hacerle ciclo infinito hasta que se cumpla la condición

Comment: Has intentado agregando un `try`: intento buscar elemento,  `except:` `pass`  o `print("No se encontro elemento")` ?

Comment: boton ¿que devuelve si no encuentra nada?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función que compruebe si el botón existe. Para ello crea un bucle del que se escapa cuando se detecta el botón:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('www.fhfhfhfh.com')


def esperar_al_boton(xpath):

    boton = None

    while not boton:
        try:
            boton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        except:
            boton = None

    return boton



boton = esperar_al_boton('//a[@href="../form_C.."]')

boton.click()
```

La función **esperar_al_boton** devuelve el botón sólo cuando este existe. A continuación puedes manipular el botón con la seguridad de que lo has capturado.